# Create synonyms and use regular expressions to find keyword

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, pattern-matching, corpus

**Background:**

I want to use regular expressions to search for a keyword. However, my keyword has multiple synonyms. For example, the keyword `positive`  can have the following words that I consider as equal to `positive`: `"+", "pos", "POS", "Positive", "POSITIVE"`

I've tried looking [Create a dataframe with NLTK synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646310/create-a-dataframe-with-nltk-synonyms) and http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html but I don't think it is quite what I am looking for

**Goals:**

1) create synonyms for a given keyword (e.g. `positive`)

2) search for a keyword (e.g. `positive`) in a corpus using regular expressions

**Example:**

```
toy_corpus = 'patient is POS which makes them ideal to treatment '
```

I think the steps to getting this would look something like this:

1) define synonyms for the `positive`
 e.g. `positive` = `["pos", "POS", "Positive", "POSITIVE", "+"]`

2) use regular expression to find the keyword `POS`

**Question**

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import re
question = "patient is POS which makes them ideal to treatment. And the the positive"
find=["pos","POS","positive"]

words=re.findall("\n+",question)
result = [words   for words in find if words in question.split()]
print(result)
['POS', 'positive']
```

Where \n is a word boundary.
Wiki: [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
More examples:  [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543724/python-regex-for-finding-all-words-in-a-string)
Best Regards!

Comment: quick q: what does "\n+" do?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. Just to be clear, there's no need to "install" re--it's built into Python. Also, your solution doesn't really use regex for anything. You get the same result with `[w for w in find if w in question.split()]`.

Comment: thanks ggorlen, anyways EER you can also try with \b ..is a word boundary (https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) Here you have more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543724/python-regex-for-finding-all-words-in-a-string Best Regards!

Comment: I looked at your link and still don't understand what the purpose of the `+` after `\n`?